# How to register to a SIP server by domain instead of IP address and create a SIP Account from client side?

Tags: android, sip, linphone, sip-server

I've successfully compiled Liblinphone library for android and use it to register to Brekeke SIP server and make calls between Android clients and PC client(x-Lite,linphone). but I'm facing two problems:

1. Client register to the server with their IP address instead of the domain.

   For e.g: if the server IP:192.168.10.105 and client (IP,name):(192.168.10.101,101),
   the user will registered to Brekeke as sip:101@192.168.10.101 instead of sip:101@192.168.10.105 so when I call 101 from linphone client the result is Not Found

   ```
   try{
       from = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance()
             .createLinphoneAddress("sip:101@192.168.10.105");

       proxy_cfg = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().createProxyConfig
                   ("sip:101@192.168.10.105","sip:"+from.getDomain(),null,true);

   } catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
       FileLog.e("proxy_cfg error",e);
   }

   LinphoneAuthInfo info;
   info = LinphoneCoreFactory.instance().createAuthInfo(from.getUserName(),
           "password",null,"sip:"+from.getDomain()); 

   mLinphoneCore.addAuthInfo(info);

   try {
       mLinphoneCore.addProxyConfig(proxy_cfg);
   } catch (LinphoneCoreException e) {
     FileLog.e("reg error",e);
   }

   mLinphoneCore.setDefaultProxyConfig(proxy_cfg);
   ```
2. I need to create user on the SIP server from the client side by code, is this possible using Liblinphone or I should implement it by my self?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply by using DNS SRV which keep tracking the clients IP